# How to define index property in typescript interface

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

There is a list of keys can be enum, array anything like `keys = ["x","y","z"]`

Need to implement an interface which can have key from this array

something like:

```
interface Points {
   [index: keys]: string
}
```

But this doesn't work as index can only be string or number.

What is better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they keys are known at compile-time you could do something like this:

```
type Keys = 'x' | 'y' | 'z';

type Points = {
  [key in Keys]: string;
}
```

This will require a `Point` record to have all the keys. You can make them optional with `[key in Keys]?: string`.

If the keys are not known at compile-time, you can't really type check it with Typescript can you ;)

Comment: Consider `Record<Keys, string>`. It is built in type